# Lodash - Aggregate values in JSON object without specifying keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to get a sum of values in a JSON array grouped by a `shop_id` and key, and get the output in the same format. I tried doing it on the DB since I am not familiar with Lodash at all but I reckon sending and receiving data from DB would not be as efficient.

With an array like this:

```
[
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 2, "skateboard": 5},
        shop_id: 6321
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 1, "skateboard": 3},
        shop_id: 6243
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 3, "skateboard": 4},
        shop_id: 6243
    }
]
```

The output should look like:

```
[
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 2, "skateboard": 5},
        shop_id: 6321
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 4, "skateboard": 7},
        shop_id: 6243
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this with Lodash? Or are there better ways to handle it without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

What it does is:

- Creates an empty accumulator object
- Loops trough the array and puts each value at [shop_id] position in the accumulator
- If there's an object already at that position, then merges them
- Gets just the values of the accumulator object to make an array

```js
const input = [
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 2, "skateboard": 5},
        shop_id: 6321
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 1, "skateboard": 3},
        shop_id: 6243
    },
    {
        sales: {"bicycle": 3, "skateboard": 4},
        shop_id: 6243
    }
];

// Output of input.reduce is an object. To get array we simply just use the values in this object
const output = Object.values(

    // Array.prototype.reduce loops through the array
    // And ads all the values into the acumulator by running your custom function
    input.reduce(

        // Custom accumulator function
        (accumulator, value) => {

            // If there's already an object at this position (position is the unique shop_id)
            if (accumulator[value.shop_id]) {

                // Merge the old and the new object
                // Loop through all the keys of the new object
                Object.entries(value.sales).forEach(
                    ([key, number]) => {

                        // If this key is already present in the old object
                        if (accumulator[value.shop_id].sales[key]) {
                            // Sum the old and the new value
                            accumulator[value.shop_id].sales[key] += number;
                        } else {
                            // Set the key to the new value
                            accumulator[value.shop_id].sales[key] = number;
                        }
                    }
                );

            // There is no object yet at this position
            } else {

                // Make a deep copy to avoid modifiing the input
                // And put it at this position
                accumulator[value.shop_id] = {
                    shop_id: value.shop_id,
                    sales: { ...value.sales },
                };
            }

            // Return the modified acumulator
            return accumulator;

        }, {} //The initial accumulator (empty object)
    )
);

console.log(output);
```